# How to double Image Size on Click

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, mouse

I am trying to make it so that when I click on an image the image width and height double but every time I click on the Image it disappears and the width and height go to 0

```
<img src="pic1.jpg" onclick="imgDouble(this)">
<script>
 function imgDouble(x){
    x.style.width *= 2;
    x.style.height *= 2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's probably not working because you have no style for the image, try getting the images width and then multiplying it before applying it to the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined the width and height for the image explicitly. So, you need to use [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientheight) to get its width and height first and then multiply it by 2:

```
 function imgDouble(x){
    x.style.width = x.clientWidth * 2;
    x.style.height = x.clientHeight * 2;
}
```

There are other alternatives that you can use x.width and x.height instead of x.style.width and x.style.height.

Or, to get exactly the image width you may use x.naturalWidth and x.naturalHeight.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I'm also trying to use a couple other functions on the same image, could they be interfering?


        <img src="pic1.jpg" onclick="imgSize(this)" onmouseout='imgReset(this)' onmouseover="imgBorder(this)">
   

     <script type="text/javascript">
    function imgSize(x){
        x.style.width = x.naturalWidth * 2;
        x.style.height = x.naturalHeight * 2;
       }
       function imgBorder(x) {
        x.style.border="1px solid red";
    }
       function imgReset(x){
        x.style.width="200px";
        x.style.border="";
        }
        </script>

Answer (score 0):

You might change the name of your function from `imgDouble(x)` to `imgSize(x)`. Try that.

Comment: I had it like that in my code but forgot to add it to the question, but thank you

Comment: use then clientWidth instead width  x.style.width = x.clientWidth * 2 and you don't need to do with height

Answer (score 0):

You have to change to

```
 <img src="pic1.jpg" onclick="imgDouble(this)">
```

because your function is imgDouble();